Wikipedia illustration for co- and contra-variant coordinates is wrong?
Searching for a picture of co-contra-variant coordinates for the simple case of Euclidean plane I found this animation in Wiki:

I believe it is completely wrong and misleading. Axes for covariant coordinates do not coincide with those for contravariant ones. Instead, the covariant e_y should be perpendicular to contravariant e_x and the covariant e_x perpendicular to contravariant e_y. In animation, if contravariant e_y leans towards e_x that stands still, the covariant e_y should stand still and e_x move away from e_y.
Also, the scalar values of the covariant coordinates have nothing to do with the orthogonal projection on the axes for contravariant coordinates.
But maybe Wiki is right and it is just me who got it incorrectly?
Edit: as requested in the comments, here I add the article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors
But as far as I can see, the text of the article is perfectly fine, it is just the illustration that contradicts the text.

Please include links to the relevant sources.

Wrong or not. Watching this makes one dizzy. I prefer to explain co- and contravariant transformations this way.
